# CDF of Order Statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Why when finding the CDF of Yn and Zn do you find P(Y_n<=y) as opposed to P(Y_n<=y_n)? Similarly with Z_n.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cdf of $Y_n$ can be called $F_{Y_n}(w)$, or $F_{Y_n}(t)$, or $F_{Y_n}(y)$, or $F_{Y_n}(y)$, or $G(y)$, it doesn't matter. If for example we like the variable symbol $t$, we can say
$$F_{Y_n}(t)=\Pr(Y_n\le t).$$
It might have been nice to call the variable by the name $y_n$, but that is perhaps a needlessly complicated name for a variable.

Comment: Ok, what if you replaced Z_n with Y_1, could you then replace z with y?

Comment: You can use any variable names you like. If there are two random variables involved, it is a good idea to use different names for the variables involved, though strictly speaking it is not necessary. It is also useful to use names for variables that remind you of what random variables they are associated with. Hence $y$ with $Y_n$. Actually, there was no good reason to call $Y_n$ by that name, the $n$ is understood. The $Y_n$ notation might be useful if there were various $n$ (sample sizes) in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All CDFs are functions of a real variable, not just limited to values of the RV. For discrete RVs, the CDF will jump at each of the discrete values by the amount of the probability mass associated with that value.

For example, if you have a RV X representing "heads" and "tails", it might assume the values $0$ and $1$ with probability $\frac12$ each. The CDF is

$$F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x<0\\
\frac12 & 0\leq x < 1 \\
1 & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

so $F_X(-36)=0$, $F_X(\frac2{17})=\frac12$, and $F_X(\frac{12345}{12344})=1$.